# Need mysql data with grouped values based on column values in php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have table schema as below

```
name   type  total
name1  type1  10
name1  type1  10
name1  type2  20
name1  type3  30
name2  type1  30
name2  type2  40
name2  type3  50
name2  type4  25
```

i need output as

```
name  type1 type2 type3 type4
name1 20    20     30    0
name2 30    40     50    25
```

How can i achieve this using php and mysql. Can anyone please help me out to solve this

> Note: Here the type1,type2.. are dynamic names which cannot be
>   hardcoded

Comment: What is stopping you? Where is your code? Where is your query? What errors are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select name, if(type='type1', sum(type),0) as type1, 
if(type='type2', sum(type),0) as type2 .................... from table_name group by name
```

Comment: it says "truncated incorrect double value". And also i have updated my question as last note which i missed out to mention

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
SET @sql = NULL;
        SELECT
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
            CONCAT(
              'MAX(IF(type = ''',
              type,
              ''', total, NULL)) AS ',
              type
            )
          ) INTO @sql
        FROM order_products_sizes;

        SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT name, ', @sql, ' 
                           FROM tablename group by name');

        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```